# Adyen UPI client integration get status

Tags: javascript, web, upi, adyen

I am somehow trying to get the status (error,success) after paying through the UPI app. I already end up in the onAdditionalDetails() function but here I somehow don't have the possibility to query the status. Is there maybe something needed to get this information in the state object?

```
async initAdyen_newurl() {
    let config = null;
    config = {
        ...this.config.adyenConfig,
        onPaymentCompleted: (result, component) => {
            console.info("onPaymentCompleted");
            console.info(result, component);
        },
        onError: (error, component) => {
            console.error("onError");
            console.error(error.name, error.message, error.stack, component);
        },
        onAdditionalDetails: (state, component) => {
            const actionUrl = "hardcoded for the moment"
            const obj = {
                paymentMethodType: component.props.paymentMethodType,
                url: actionUrl,
                method: "post",
                type: "redirect",
                paymentData: component.props.paymentData
            }
            component.props.createFromAction(obj, {}).mount("#id");
        },
    };
    AdyenCheckout(config)
        .then((checkout) => {
            // init stuff
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(`url failure ${error.message}`);
        });
},
```

I can also redirect to the next page using createFromAction(), but this just happens in both Success and Error. However, this should only happen in Success. I hope that was somehow understandable. Many Thanks

edited: i am using version 5.23.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow involves an additional step (3DS) so the `onAdditionalDetails` handler is invoked. From there you can add an extra call to `/payments/details` to fetch the payment status.

The response includes the `resultCode` to inform the shopper of the payment status.

Here is an example:

```
...
  onPaymentCompleted: (result, component) => {
    handleServerResponse(result, component);
  },
  onAdditionalDetails: async (response, _component) => {
    // call server
    const paymentDetailsResponse = await callServer("/api/paymentDetails", response);
  // obtain payment status
  const result = paymentDetailsResponse.resultCode
  },
  onError: (error, component) => {
    console.error(error.name, error.message, error.stack, component);
  }

// Calls your server endpoints
async function callServer(url, data) {
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : "",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });
```

In the backend perform the `paymentsDetails` call to obtain the Payment status from the Adyen platform:

```
// Check payment result
app.post("/api/paymentDetails", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await checkout.paymentsDetails({
      details: req.body.data.details,
      paymentData: req.body.data.paymentData,
    });
    res.json(response); 
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error: ${err.message}, error code: ${err.errorCode}`);
    res.status(err.statusCode).json(err.message);
  }
});
```

See [Confirm an additional action on your server](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/advanced-use-cases/additional-actions)

Comment: first of all, thank you for the answer. I can't get into the onPaymentCompleted() function. Have also defined this in my configuration object. I end up in the onAdditionalDetails() function in both success and error cases.

Comment: Can you maybe post the code when you define the component including the onPaymentCompleted()?

Comment: i edited my config. As i said, i can see the Adyen UPI message "Open your UPI app to confirm the payment". But unfortunately afterwards I end up in onAdditionalDetails in case of success as well as in case of error without having the possibility to get the actual status.

Comment: if this helps, i am using version 5.23.0

Comment: In additio,  what ive seen in the network tab (dev tools), that they are alot of responses (https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/services/PaymentInitiation/v1/status?clientKey=KEY) from adyen about the current payment status with all the information i need. Does this have to be captured somehow? but have not found an example

Comment: I have tried to replicate the issue (using UPI) but in my case the `onPaymentCompleted` fires accordingly: I use a simulator so I think it works differently in your case. I believe the issue is that there is an additional step involved (3DS) so the workflow involves calling the `onAdditionalDetails`. From there you can add an extra call to `/payments/details` to fetch the payment status. See https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/web-drop-in/advanced-use-cases/additional-actions#step-2-confirm-the-result-of-an-additional-action

Comment: I am going to update the answer to include the last comment

Comment: I am using a simulator for faking the payment response, too. Is There a js implemenation example for this additional payment status call?

Comment: So this /payments/details must Not be made from the backend?

Comment: I have added sample code that performs the call to `/payment/details` to obtain the Payment resultCode